# Mixed Content Error in IE7 with html5shiv and SSL

Tags: asp.net, html, ssl, internet-explorer-7, html5shiv

I'm developing an ASP.Net app that is using html5shiv and ssl.  For some reason I am getting mixed content errors in IE7 using html5shiv.  If I remove html5shiv the errors go away.  I'm also using update panels and master pages if that matters.  Any ideas?

Edit: After further testing it appears to be a combination between html5shiv and a stylesheet.  If either are excluded, no mixed content error.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/html5shiv.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/global.css" />
```

Solution:  I had a data uri on a header style.  Removing the uri solved the problem.

Comment: Is your site running under SSL?

Comment: Yes.  See edit as well.

Comment: Could you edit your question again and show the HTML for the two offending links please?

Comment: This ended up being an issue with a css style with a data URI. Apparently IE7 recognizes this as mixed content.  The modernizer was dynamically loading a header tag which is the element the offending css style was applied to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being an issue with a css style with a data URI. Apparently IE7 recognizes this as mixed content. The modernizer was dynamically loading a header tag which is the element the offending css style was applied to.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the externally hosted html5shiv (on a CDN)? If so, download the file and host it yourself on the same server.

Comment: No.  html5shiv and the offending css file are hosted on the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `https`, you need to make sure that all files are served via `https`. If you have any `http` downloads on the page, you'll get mixed content warnings.

It sounds like your html5shiv file may be being served via `http`, and this is causing the problem.

If you're downloading it from a third party site, check whether that site allows `https` downloads. If not, you may need to serve it yourself.

Comment: It is being served via https.  Only a problem in IE7 as well.